# Why is netcat not connecting over ipv6

Tags: linux, iptables, ip

For example, trying to connect to google's mail servers.

```
root@mail2:~# nc -vC 209.85.232.26 smtp
Connection to 209.85.232.26 25 port [tcp/smtp] succeeded!
220 mx.google.com ESMTP u65si15520060qkf.84 - gsmtp
_



root@mail2:~# nc -vC 2607:f8b0:400d:c0a::1a smtp
_
```

It just hangs there.

My ifconfig -

```
root@mail2:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b2:94:3b:b0:8c:35  
          inet addr:104.131.80.101  Bcast:104.131.127.255  Mask:255.255.192.0
          inet6 addr: 2604:a880:800:10::1a40:e001/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::b094:3bff:feb0:8c35/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Comment: Did you test, if you can ``ping6`` the google server? From your post it is not clear, if its only a netcat problem or possibly a ipv6 setup problem or a connection problem to google.

Comment: In IPv6, a hang would mean the TCP syn packets were being sent but thrown away by a firewall which would appear as a "hang" to the client.  The same might be true with IPv6.